# codeigniter htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a big application on codeigniter 1.7 and I update it to 2.1 but i have a problem (404 page not found ) my current htaccess is :

```
rewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

rewriteRule ^admin(.*) index.php/admin$1
rewriteRule ^supervisor/([0-9]+)(.*) index.php/supervisor_$1/$2
rewriteRule ^(login|logoff)(.*) index.php/base/$1$2
rewriteRule ^(files|attachment|meeting|thread|attachments|profile|search|roles|cat)(.*) index.php/moder/$1$2
rewriteRule ^(about|contact|new_majlis|stats)(.*) index.php/page/$1$2
rewriteRule ^(2.2-release-notes)(.*) index.php/page/release_notes
```

can you please help me ?

Comment: Why do you have `enter code here`

Comment: sorry my first time asking question

Comment: You need a bit more detail. What URL are you requesting?

Comment: am trying the load the login page 
http://localhost/majalis/login
this is the default_controller
$route['default_controller'] = "moder/index";

Comment: is it a "codeigniter 404" or your server "404"? I doubt it is a htaccess problem - it is more likely something you forgot to change in the upgrade (like new controller convention names or something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, routing like this should be done in your `application/config/routes.php` file. I recommend adding entries such as:

```
$route['supervisor/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'supervisor/$1/$2'; // This also looks hackish
$route['login/(:any)'] = 'base/$1';
$route['logoff/(:any)'] = 'base/$1';


$route['about/(:any)'] = 'page/about/$1';
$route['contact/(:any)'] = 'page/contact/$1';
$route['new_majlis/(:any)'] = 'page/new_majlis/$1';
$route['stats/(:any)'] = 'page/stats/$1';
$route['2.2-release-notes/(:any)'] = 'page/stats/$1';
```

I'm also assuming you want to have "pretty" pages; **/admin** instead of **/index.php/admin**

For your `.htaccess` file, you can replace all of the above with:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

That will make sure that CodeIgniter is handling all requests.

---

**For your 404 error:**

Cherry pick apart your `config.php`. Quite a few things changed, so it's best to use the vanilla 2.1 version and filling it in with your previously configured variables from the 1.7 version. The same applies to some other files in your `application/config` folder as well.

The changelog is endlessly useful for specifics: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html

Comment: Check your Apache error logs. What pages are coming up with errors?